# 4G回線（LTE）でWKWebViewを使ってWebページを表示する方法について

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

WKWebViewで「http://example.com/」が表示できません。
(また、別のURLに変更しても同様の結果です。真っ白になります。)
wifiを有効にすると表示でき、4Gで接続すると表示できません。
（safariでは4Gで表示できます。）
また、App Transport SecurityのHTTPは許可をしています。
WKWebViewを使った他のアプリでは表示できるのに、何故か表示できない事象になってしまいました。

ご存知の方がいれば、ご教授願います。

端末情報：iOS9.3、iPhone6
キャリア：au

Comment: 他の端末の同じOSバージョンでsimを入れ替えて試したら、問題なく表示できました。
複数端末やっても同じ結果なので多分自分の端末独自の問題っぽいです。
WKWebViewが原因だと思ったらWebViewでも同じ結果でした。
なぜ表示できないのだ。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
設定のモバイルデータ通信がオフになっていたのが問題だったようです。
オンに変更したら無事表示できるようになりました。